# i am using SCRecorder. After applying filter on video it automatically add black screen in right side in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, filtering

i am facing some issue on video filter using SCRecorder library. When i applying filter on video is automatically crop and add some black pard added on right side of the screen.

My code is here:

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let movieURL = VideoAlbumManager.sharedSingleton().returnPathUrl(effcetVideoUrl)
        let aVideoAsset   = AVURLAsset.init(url: effcetVideoUrl)
        let exportSession = SCAssetExportSession(asset: (self.recordSession?.assetRepresentingSegments1(aVideoAsset))!)
        exportSession.videoConfiguration.filter = SCFilter(ciFilterName: modelClass.effectFile)
        exportSession.videoConfiguration.preset = SCPresetHighestQuality
        exportSession.audioConfiguration.preset = SCPresetHighestQuality
        exportSession.videoConfiguration.maxFrameRate = 35
        exportSession.outputUrl = movieURL!
         exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4.rawValue
        exportSession.delegate = self
        exportSession.contextType = SCContextType(rawValue: 0)!
        print("exportSession.outputUrl:-\(String(describing: movieURL!))")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let overlay = SCWatermarkOverlayView()
        overlay.date = self.recordSession?.date
        exportSession.videoConfiguration.overlay = overlay
        print("Starting exporting")
        }
        let time: CFTimeInterval = CACurrentMediaTime()
       exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            print("Export")
            if !exportSession.cancelled {
                print("Completed compression in \(CACurrentMediaTime() - time)")
            }

            let error: Error? = exportSession.error
            if exportSession.cancelled {
                print("Export was cancelled")
            }
            else if error == nil {
                if isSave == "1" {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.saveToCameraRoll(URL: exportSession.outputUrl as NSURL?)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                        self.playerView.clean()
                        self.playerView .removeFromSuperview()
                        self.stopAnimating()
                        print("dfr==================f\(exportSession.outputUrl!)")
                        self.effectVideoUrl = exportSession.outputUrl! as NSURL
                        self.playerView = GUIPlayerView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(105), width:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/2))//1
                        self.playerView.delegate = self
                        self.view.addSubview(self.playerView)//2
                        self.playerView.videoURL = exportSession.outputUrl!
                        self.playerView.prepareAndPlayAutomatically(false)
                        self.playerView .stop()
                    })
                } 
            }else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                    self.stopAnimating()
                    print("elseelseelseerrorerrorerror:66666-\(String(describing: error))")
                })
            }

        })
    }
```

Description of link

https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder/issues/425

Comment: Did you get any solution? If yes then please help me I am facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can not solve your problem with your library, but normally, if you crop a video and the layer has no alpha pixel buffer attached to it, the alpha pixels will be black.

If you would use an AVPlayerLayer you could solve the issue with one line of code.

```
playerLayer.pixelBufferAttributes = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String): kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
```

Maybe it will help you to solve your problem.